# Does anybody have information on this tube?

Tags: apple-ii, crt-monitor

[image: Tube from applecolor monitor a2m6020]

I need to know if this is a color or monochrome tube. It’s in an applecolor A2M6020

Comment: If original, the A2M6020 was a color composite monitor. How many inputs are there (does it have 1 or 3 guns)?

Comment: i can’t really tell but it looks like 3

Comment: The moniter only displays green, so i think the blue and red guns are broken.

Comment: You could have posted a picture of relevant parts like of the electron gun driver PCB on the back of the CRT. But I found one picture on the net with same Samsung model tube and it was a color CRT.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that it’s supposed to be a color crt, but the red and blue electron guns are bad.

Comment: You still seem to guess without proof that the electron guns are bad, instead of figuring out if it is some simpler problem which is fixable.

Comment: what would that simpler problem be

Comment: The electronic circuitry that drives the guns.

Comment: @SottoVoce that doesn't necessarily sound simpler. :)

Comment: @JeremyP It does. It might be a simple problem that is fixable by anyone with basic electronic skills. If the CRT itself is dead, it is likely not fixable (not even with expert level glass blowing skills).

Comment: You can always tell if a CRT is colour or not by looking at the screen.  A uniform phosphor coating is monochrome, dots indicate colour.

Comment: I had monochrome CRTs that were variously green, orange, white. That was the phosphor. Green does not necessarily mean that only one gun of three is working.